# How to set modal header fixed?

Tags: html, css

I created a modal that has a title label or header but I want it in a fixed position and will not scroll while scrolling the modal.

```
 #empDetailsLabel{

     background-color: #203A43 ;
     height: 5%;
     width: 100%;     
     padding: 10px;
     position: fixed;
 }
```

empDetailsLabel is the ID of the div of the modal header. I already set the position to fixed but the header still disappears when I scroll down.

***HTML view button Modal:***

```
<a href="#Employee" id="view">View</a>
                    <input type="button" id="delete" value="Delete">
                    <div class="viewEmp" id="Employee">   
                        <div class="empContainer">

                            <div id="empDetailsLabel">
                            <label>Employee Details</label>
                            </div>

                            <label class="labelPerInfo">Personal Information</label><br><br>
                        <div id="personalInfo1">    
                        <label>First Name</label><br>                      
                        <input type="text" id="firstName" readonly/><br><br>   


                        <label style="font-size: small;">Last Name</label><br>  
                        <input type="text" id="lastName" readonly/><br><br>  


                        <label>Address</label><br>
                        <textarea id="address" cols="2" rows="3" style="resize:none" readonly></textarea><br><br>

                        <label>Email</label><br>  
                        <input type="email" id="email" readonly/><br><br>  



                        </div>

                        <div id="personalInfo2">
                            <label>Middle Name</label><br>
                            <input type="text" id="middleName" readonly/><br><br>

                            <label>Gender</label><br>
                            <input type="text" id="gender" readonly/><br><br> 

                            <label>Date of Birth</label><br>
                            <input type="text" id="bday" readonly/><br><br><br>  

                            <label>Contact Number</label><br>
                            <input type="number" id="contactNo" readonly/><br><br>  
                        </div> 

                        <hr class="new1" width="100%"/>

                        <div id="workInfo">

                            <label class="labelPerInfo">Work Information</label><br><br>

                            <div id="personalInfo1">    
                                <label>First Name</label><br>                      
                                <input type="text" id="firstName" readonly/><br><br>   


                                <label style="font-size: small;">Last Name</label><br>  
                                <input type="text" id="lastName" readonly/><br><br>  


                                <label>Address</label><br>
                                <textarea id="address" cols="2" rows="3" style="resize:none" readonly></textarea><br><br>

                                <label>Email</label><br>  
                                <input type="email" id="email" readonly/><br><br>  



                                </div>

                                <div id="personalInfo2">
                                    <label>Middle Name</label><br>
                                    <input type="text" id="middleName" readonly/><br><br>

                                    <label>Gender</label><br>
                                    <input type="text" id="gender" readonly/><br><br> 

                                    <label>Date of Birth</label><br>
                                    <input type="text" id="bday" readonly/><br><br><br>  

                                    <label>Contact Number</label><br>
                                    <input type="number" id="contactNo" readonly/><br><br>  
                                </div> 
                        </div>




                        <a href="#" id="close">Close</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

This is the view button that will open the modal and the modal itself.

Comment: Can you share your HTML code?

Comment: Thanks. You're code is working fine to keep that bar fixed at the top. see here https://jsfiddle.net/trw530q1/4/  Can you post all of your CSS too? maybe there is something going on there.

Comment: @John see here: https://jsfiddle.net/seLfywz9/1/

Comment: Understood.  Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you need to use sticky,  but since you already have something at the top fixed, you need to set top position to tell it where it stick too.  See here:

```css
body {
    background-color: #d9d9d9;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}


.titleBar{
    background-color: #203A43;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    
    
   
}

.titleBar input[type=button]{
    height: 100%;
    width: 15%  ;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    background-color: #203A43;
    color: white;

    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

.titleBar input:hover{
    background-color:#325a67;
}
.titleBar input:focus{
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #325a67
    
}

 #executives{
     margin-top: 5%;
     width: 1260px;
     font-family: 'Lucida Sans';
     color: white;
     border: 1px solid white;
     text-align: center;
     height: 120px;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     background-color: white;
     
 }

 th{     
    background-color: #203A43;
    color: white;
 }

 #executives td #executives th{
     border: 1px solid #ddd;
     border-width: 1000px;
     padding: 8px;
 }
 tr{
     color: black;
     height: 40px;
 }
 tr:nth-child(even){
     background-color:#dddddd;   
 }
 td input{
     border-radius: 5px;
     width: 50px;
     height: 25px;
     outline: none;
     border: none;
 }

#view {
     background-color: #2eb82e;
     text-decoration:none;
     color: black;
     font-size: medium;
     border-radius: 15%;
     padding: 2%;
 }
 #view:hover{
    background-color: #29a329;
 }  
 #delete{
     background-color: #e62e00;

 }
 #delete:hover{
    background-color: #cc2900;
 }
 #close{
     float: right;
     margin: 5%;
 }

 .empContainer{
     position: fixed;
     background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
     border: 1px solid #000; 
     left: 50%;
     border-radius: 5px;
     width: 1000px;
     max-width: 100%;
     overflow-y: scroll;
     height: 400px;
     max-height: 100%;
     


     -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -200vh);
     -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -200vh);
     transform: translate(-50%, -200vh);

     -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 200ms ease-out;
     transition: transform 200ms ease-out;
 }

 .viewEmp:before{
     content: "";
     position: fixed;
     display: none;
     background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
     top:0;
     left:0;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;

 }
 .viewEmp:target .empContainer{
     top: 20%;

    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);

 }

 .viewEmp:target:before{
     display: block;
 }

 #empDetailsLabel{
    
     background-color: #203A43 ;
     height: 5%;
     width: 100%;     
     padding: 10px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
 }

 #empDetailsLabel label{
     color: white;
     
 }

 #personalInfo1{
     
     text-align: left;
     padding-top: 20px;    
     float: left;
     max-width: 100%;
     
 }

 #firstName{
     border: gray solid 1px;
     width: 250px;
 }
 #middleName{
    border: gray solid 1px;
    width: 250px;
}
#lastName{
    border: gray solid 1px;
    width: 250px;
}
#gender{
    border: gray solid 1px;
    width: 250px;
}
#address{
    border: gray solid 1px;
    width: 250px;
}
#email{
    border: gray solid 1px;
    width: 250px;
}
#contactNo{
    border: gray solid 1px;
    width: 250px;
}
#bday{
    border: gray solid 1px;
    width: 250px;
}
#personalInfo2{
    padding-left: 200px;;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 20px;

    max-width: 100%;
    float: left;
    width: 300px
}
.labelPerInfo{
    float: left;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#Employee" id="view">View</a>
                    <input type="button" id="delete" value="Delete">
                    <div class="viewEmp" id="Employee">   
                        <div class="empContainer">

                            <div id="empDetailsLabel">
                            <label>Employee Details</label>
                            </div>

                            <label class="labelPerInfo">Personal Information</label><br><br>
                        <div id="personalInfo1">    
                        <label>First Name</label><br>                      
                        <input type="text" id="firstName" readonly/><br><br>   


                        <label style="font-size: small;">Last Name</label><br>  
                        <input type="text" id="lastName" readonly/><br><br>  


                        <label>Address</label><br>
                        <textarea id="address" cols="2" rows="3" style="resize:none" readonly></textarea><br><br>

                        <label>Email</label><br>  
                        <input type="email" id="email" readonly/><br><br>  



                        </div>

                        <div id="personalInfo2">
                            <label>Middle Name</label><br>
                            <input type="text" id="middleName" readonly/><br><br>

                            <label>Gender</label><br>
                            <input type="text" id="gender" readonly/><br><br> 

                            <label>Date of Birth</label><br>
                            <input type="text" id="bday" readonly/><br><br><br>  

                            <label>Contact Number</label><br>
                            <input type="number" id="contactNo" readonly/><br><br>  
                        </div> 

                        <hr class="new1" width="100%"/>

                        <div id="workInfo">

                            <label class="labelPerInfo">Work Information</label><br><br>

                            <div id="personalInfo1">    
                                <label>First Name</label><br>                      
                                <input type="text" id="firstName1" readonly/><br><br>   


                                <label style="font-size: small;">Last Name</label><br>  
                                <input type="text" id="lastName1" readonly/><br><br>  


                                <label>Address</label><br>
                                <textarea id="address" cols="2" rows="3" style="resize:none" readonly></textarea><br><br>

                                <label>Email</label><br>  
                                <input type="email" id="email1" readonly/><br><br>  



                                </div>

                                <div id="personalInfo2">
                                    <label>Middle Name</label><br>
                                    <input type="text" id="middleName1" readonly/><br><br>

                                    <label>Gender</label><br>
                                    <input type="text" id="gender1" readonly/><br><br> 

                                    <label>Date of Birth</label><br>
                                    <input type="text" id="bday1" readonly/><br><br><br>  

                                    <label>Contact Number</label><br>
                                    <input type="number" id="contactNo1" readonly/><br><br>  
                                </div> 
                        </div>




                        <a href="#" id="close">Close</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks! But I got a white space above the header now

Comment: Oh just set the top to 0 then.

Comment: No problem.  Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set the `position` property of the modal header to `sticky` instead of `fixed`.

For more information, you can visit : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp